# how to add a directory path with spaces as a java option

Tags: java, grails

when I try to run a grails build with a work.dir configured like that

```
grails -Dgrails.work.dir="../my project/target" clean --non-interactive
```

I get

Error Script not found: Project/target

I already tried many different variations, like

```
grails -Dgrails.work.dir="../my\ project/target" clean --non-interactive
```

or even

```
grails "-Dgrails.work.dir=../my project/target" clean --non-interactive
```

but nothing works - is this a grails issue?

Comment: Can you try replacing the space with `%20`?

Comment: no, this does not lead to the error but would configure a different directory (named my%20project)

Comment: It actually did, or you are speculating?  If it is using a URL internally, like "file://../my project/target", then the %20 should resolve to a space.  Is this on Windows, or are you using *nix?

Comment: I tried it on my Mac and it did create that directory

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-Dgrails.work.dir="../'my project'/target"
```

Woks for me in Linux, tested with 2.3

Comment: yes this works on OS X too, but it does not look very "good", I am not sure if there is a problem in Grails or if Java vm options need to be handled like that

Comment: Yea true, but it works which is the main thing! I think most options passed in strings will have this problem, not just grails